# How do I get the sum of each line depending on the team name?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called **data**:

[image]

And I would like to get the sum of each row as column name, like this:
[image]

What is the correct SQL statement I need? I've been trying with CASE or IF but I just don't get the right answer.

Comment: Consider normalising your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *need aggregation* :

```
select 
    sum(case when team = 'team business' then total_points else 0 end) as total_business,
    sum(case when team = 'team tech' then total_points else 0 end) as total_tech
from
    data d;
```